# Php y localStorage: ¿Cómo recibir datos de localStorage para guardar en variable de php?

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

Un saludo.
Me encuentro investigando sobre localStorage, quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de capturar una variable almacenada en el localStorage y para asignarla a una variable de php.

Archivo funciones.js:

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem('user','Juan');
</script>
```

Archivo index.php:

```
<?
// Algo como esto:
//$user = localstorage.getItem('user');
?>
<html>...</html>
```

Si esto no es posible, cual podría ser una manera de traer variables de js a php (estoy evitando tocar el html y de no usar $_get)

Comment: Tendrías que usar AJAX en este caso... ya que PHP se ejecuta en el servidor, y para que envíes datos desde localStorage a PHP, es necesario utilizar alguna forma de comunicación entre el cliente y el servidor...

Comment: efectivamente debes usar ajax.

Comment: También puedes  utilizar cookies,  que aunque se guardan en el cliente como el localStorage, estas  se envían al servidor  con  cada solicitud http,  por tanto puedes  crear la cookie en javascript y leerla  en php y viceversa.

Comment: Qué método usas para hacer el request al servidor!?. Si fuera mediante un formulario vía POST puedes obtener del localstorage y asignar el valor a un input hidden.

Comment: Disculpa no leí la última condición que pones en tu pregunta; efectivamente lo "ideal" sería Ajax.